# JSTL Syntax replaceAll()

Tags: jstl

I'm using start JSTL. Then I use `${fn:replaceAll('','','')}` this function.
Third parameter is must be `<a href="pageContext.request.contextPath"/people/id.shtml>name</a>`
then id and name is variable. But I can't write this anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually want is:

```
${fn:replace(text, 'before', 'after')}
```

> Returns a string resulting from replacing in an input string all occurrences of a "before" string into an "after" substring.

Note the function is not called `replaceAll`.

If that doesn't work for you, then please provide a more detailed description of the error or behavior that occurs.

Comment: thank you for reply. 'm using ${fn:replace(text,'searchValue','<a href='mylink'>searchvalue</a>')} if it found searchValue.add anchor tag. but how to add anchor tag. i thinks i am mistake double and single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your comment I think you want something like this:

```
<c:choose>
     <c:when test="${fn:contains(searchValue, searchString)}">
           <a href='mylink'>searchValue</a>
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
           searchValue
     </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```